# How can I filter stdout

Tags: shell, stdout

I use the mysqldump tool to create dumps of my database, e.g.

```
mysqldump database > database.sql
```

Despite having added the option '--lock-tables=FALSE', the .sql file contains lines like:

```
LOCK TABLES "tableXYZ" WRITE;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Is it possible to filter out these lines before they are written into the .sql file?

Comment: Try something like `mysqldump database|FILTER_COMMAND > database.sql`, making use of unix pipes, where FILTER_COMMAND can be grep or awk or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysqldump database | sed  -r '/^(UN)?LOCK/d' > database.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

using `sed` you can do it by:

```
mysqldump database |sed -e "/LOCK/d"> database.sql
```

this command will remove all the lines containing "LOCK" before putting it in `database.sql`